# C programming, array of char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a program which takes out strings from a text file, and stores them into an array.

Suppose from the text file I get delims: "one", "dfs", "w342"

After I get these delims, I want to create an array with the same size as number of tokens found, and elements in the array have to be char pointers to "one", "dfs", "w342".

```
int lexer(FILE* file){

char line[50];
char* delim;    
char* tokenArray[100];
int i = 0;

while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),file)){
    printf("%s\n", line);

    if(is_empty(line) == 1)
        continue;

    delim = strtok(line," ");


    if(delim == NULL)
        printf("%s\n", "ERROR");

    while(delim != NULL){

        if(delim[0] == '\n'){
        //rintf("%s\n", "olala");
            break;
        }
        tokenArray[i] = strdup(delim);
        printf("Token IN array: %s\n", tokenArray[i]);
        i= i+ 1;
        delim = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }   
}

printf("%s\n", tokenArray[6]);

fclose(file);
return 0;
```

Now I am getting the delims and I'm storing them into an array, but I don't think I'm doing it right because I'm not storing the pointers. I also want to send this `tokenArray` into different functions.  What should I do?

Comment: Your loop has a bug in that you did not limit the number of strings to 100 or less.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you are "not storing the pointers"? What do you think `tokenArray[i] = strdup(delim)` does? It stores a pointer in your array., Can you please show us the input file? Can you please show us the expected and actual output printed by this function? You have at least seven "tokens" in your input file? Have you tried stepping though the code, line by line, in a debugger? And if you haven't done so yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can't return the `tokenArray` to the calling function as written, though if you called other functions from the one where this code is defined, you could perfectly well pass it to those functions.  If you need to pass the array back, you'll need to dynamically allocate it and return the pointer to the array to the calling code.  As a general rule, if a function doesn't open the file, it shouldn't close it; if it does open the file, it should close it.  You're closing a file you didn't open, which is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with very small modification and you can pass the tokenArray to a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char *tokenArray[]) {
    printf("Test %s\n", tokenArray[2]);
}

int main(void) {

    char line[50];
    char *delim;
    char *tokenArray[100];
    int i = 0;
    FILE* file;

    file = fopen("data.txt","r"); // read mode

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("%s\n", line);

        delim = strtok(line, " ");


        if (delim == NULL)
            printf("%s\n", "ERROR");

        while (delim != NULL) {

            if (delim[0] == '\n') {
                //rintf("%s\n", "olala");
                break;
            }
            tokenArray[i] = strdup(delim);
            printf("Token IN array: %s\n", tokenArray[i]);
            i = i + 1;
            delim = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", tokenArray[2]);
    test(tokenArray);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

File data.txt

```
one dfs w342
```

Output

```
one dfs w342
Token IN array: one
Token IN array: dfs
Token IN array: w342
w342
Test w342
```